# NET-SNMP in Solaris 11.3 -How configure filesystem full and a process down?

Tags: solaris, snmp

i have configured the community in one Solaris 11.3 System and it works

But.. for monitoring filesystems full or an application process down, 
my question is, how must i add this control in snmp.conf?

for exemple:

rdsk /

disk /var

proc http

??

i have standalone and kernel zone machines

thanx in advance !

Max